# read nvarchar data in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, gridview, nvarchar

I am Using This Code To Read data from Oracle Database .That Data stored In Oracle is Navarchar2 data type but when It it display in gridview it looks like this.

```
Ù†ØµØ±Øª Ù…Ù†ÙˆÚ©Û
```

HEre is the code I am using to read data
**Update**

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=cms; User ID=cms20112012; Password=ramzan; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
        con.open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from V_GROW", con)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim I As Long
        da.Fill(ds, "V_GROW")
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataBind()
        For I = 0 To ds.Tables("V_GROW").Rows.Count - 1
            Dim grower As String = ds.Tables("V_GROW").Rows(I).Item("Grower Name")
grower = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(grower))
            Label1.Text = grower
        Next I
        con.close()
    End Sub
```

Please anyone tell me How can i display data in actual arabic form which i have stored in DB.

**Update**

Here is My View Query and now my data is in this form ?& ? ?????? ??? ?R

```
select ZONE_NO "Zone No",to_char(GROWER_NAME_U) "Grower Name",to_char(FATHER_NAME_U) "Father Name" from CMS_GROWER
where rownum<11
and grower_name_u is not null
```

Comment: when you change the encoding in your browser, does it help ?

Comment: @user1103342 - What is the national character set of your database?  What language is the data stored in the `V_GROM` table?  Your code appears to be attempting to convert the data into ASCII before displaying it-- are you certain that it is possible to correctly convert the underlying data to ASCII?

Comment: My database character set is WE8MSWIN1252 and I am storing My date In Arabic Form In Nvarchar2 data type

Comment: before you encoded it to ascii, when you still got "Ù†ØµØ±Øª Ù…Ù†ÙˆÚ©Û
" what was your encoding in the browser ? what's your IIS version ?

Comment: I am Using Google Chrome And IIS Built-in of Windows Server 2003 and the Browser language is English charset